# Cannot convert type error, but both types are the same?

Tags: c#

[image]

```
public static Dictionary<string, User> userList = new Dictionary<string, User>();
```

That's how "userList" gets declared in another class. BTW the name of that class is "User" the same as the type, which could cause the problem but i am not sure. I have no idea how to make this work honestly.

Here's the full script: https://pastebin.com/h56ukpgR
Some things in the script dont make sense yet because i copied some stuff from another script.

But basically i am trying to check if a nickName already exists in a static dictionary, and if so notify the user and don't do anything else.

Comment: What are the keys in the dictionary? If they're the nicknames you can lookup the key. Otherwise you can iterate all users with `foreach(User u in User.userList.Values)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`User.userList` is a `Dictionary<string, User>`. If you iterate over it, each element is a [`KeyValuePair<string, User>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.8), not a `User`.

So you can either do:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, User> kvp in User.userList)
{
    User user = kvp.Value;
}
```

Or you can iterate directly over the [dictionary's values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=netframework-4.8):

```
foreach (User user in user.userList.Values)
{
}
```

---

If the key for each `User` in your dictionary is the user's nickname, then you don't need the loop at all. Your code:

```
foreach (User u in User.userList)
{
    string uN = u.GetNickName();
    if (name == uN)
    {
        builder.WithTitle("A practice with the name you specified already exists!");
        goto EndFunction;
    }
}

EndFunction:
await ReplyAsync("", false, builder.Build());
```

Can be replaced with:

```
if (User.userList.ContainsKey(name))
{
    builder.WithTitle("A practice with the name you specified already exists!");
}

await ReplyAsync("", false, builder.Build());
```

If not, you can still simplify this code using linq's [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8):

```
if (User.userList.Values.Any(x => x.GetNickName() == name))
{
    builder.WithTitle("A practice with the name you specified already exists!");
}

await ReplyAsync("", false, builder.Build());
```

---

Finally, using `goto` in this way is not recommended. You can break out of a loop simply by using `break;`.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, an hint to solving these kinda problems is to look at the error message. Here it says:

> Cannot convert `KeyValuePair<string, User>` to `User`

That simply means the expected cast is a `KeyValuePair<string, User>` and not a `User`.

So, your code would work if you replace `User` In the loop with `KeyValuePair<string, User>`.